# How to select couple of records for editing in MySql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have around 100 entries in MySql table, that contain a specific word in field Value(in field Value I store phrases, but need to search for a specific string). I want to find all this records and manually fix them in MySql workbench. How Can I do that? I tried request

```
EDIT `Versions` WHERE `Versions`.`VersionId` IN (SELECT `Versions`.`Value` FROM `Versions` WHERE `Versions`.`Value` like 'organiz%');
```

but I get empty result and it works extremely long(more then 10 minutes for 5000 records), nevertheless just a select

```
SELECT `Versions`.`Value` FROM `Versions` WHERE `Versions`.`Value` like 'organiz%')
```

returns a couple of values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: percent signs on both sides of organiz... like '%organiz%'  unless you KNOW all versions.value will START with organiz%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK **EDIT** isn't something that mysql recognize as a command.

I don't know mysql workbench but if you wan't to find all rows containing 'organiz' you need to add a extra % at the start of the like.

```
SELECT `Versions`.`Value` FROM `Versions` WHERE `Versions`.`Value` like '%organiz%';
```

Comment: EDIT is a MySQL workbench keyword. In this case it's essentially the same as SELECT. OP should use `EDIT Versions.Value FROM Versions WHERE Versions.Value like '%organiz%';`

Answer (score 1):

You should use

`EDIT Versions.Value FROM Versions WHERE Versions.Value like '%organiz%';`

From within the MySQL Workbench query tab. Which should yield the result set that you're looking to edit.